# Are Dell PERC H200 H700 RAID cards supported by ".deb" based Linux distros?

Tags: debian, raid, hardware, dell-perc

For a Dell PowerEdge T310 that I haven't yet, I was wondering if its RAID cards are supported by distributions using ".deb" packages like Debian or Ubuntu.

On Dell's web site, I could only find drivers for Red Hat (and CentOS, Fedora) or Windows, but not for the Debian family.

Has anyone a Dell PowerEdge T310 with hardware RAID 1 based on the H200 or H700 card?

Answer (score 5):

Most PCI-based "real" SATA/SAS RAID controllers (not "fakeraid") don't need special drivers. This is not excusively the case (I'm sure a lot of us have had to scramble for HBA drivers for new Windows releases).

You'll be fine with any modern operating system on that platform. If you're doing Debian or Ubuntu from within the last 3-4 years, there'll be no issue.

Dell cards are just rebranded LSI MegaRaid devices, so the LSI management tools generally work fine with them. You can get `megacli` for most platforms.

Answer (score 3):

PERC H200, H300, H700 and so on do not require specific 3rd party drivers to function; they merely export a SCSI disk device to the OS (which can use the builtin SCSI drivers).

That said, additional drivers (in this case, a kernel module for LSI cards) can be loaded to provide extended functionality, for example to query array config/state and/or to configure it.

As stated above, as DELL PERCs are nothing more than rebranded LSI cards, you can always use `megacli` and/or other LSI utilities.

However, DELL's own `omreport` and `omconfig` utilities are,  as far I know, available in RPM format only, and with RHEL/CentOS kABI compatibility. A tar.gz packages exists, but it should contain additional RPM inside it.